# Button Text not placing correctly

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS to design an ASP:Button however - not knowing CSS very well I just can not get the text to appear in the middle of the button.

I am using this CSS

```
display: block;
float: left;
clear: left;
height: 34px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 10px 0;
vertical-align: super;
line-height: normal;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
font-variant: small-caps;
text-transform: capitalize;
color: #000000;
```

However, as you can see from the image below the result is far from satisfactory. How do I get the text to appear in the middle of the button as we would expect?

[image]

Any ideas?

The aspx file contains this code:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <label class="grey" for="signup">Username:</label>
                <input class="field" type="text" name="signup" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="23" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_register" />
            </form>
```

The full .css is here:

```
/*
Name: Sliding Login Panel with jQuery 1.3.2
Author: Jeremie Tisseau
Author URI: http://web-kreation.com/
Date: March 26, 2009
Version: 1.0

Copyright 2009 Jeremie Tisseau
"Sliding Login Panel with jQuery 1.3.2" is distributed under the GNU General Public License version 3:
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
*/

 /***** clearfix *****/
.clear
{
clear: both;
height: 0;
line-height: 0;
 }

 .clearfix:after
 {
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}

 .clearfix
 {
display: inline-block;
 }
 /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix
 {
height: 1%;
 }

 .clearfix
 {
display: block;
 }
  /* End hide from IE-mac */
 .clearfix
 {
height: 1%;
 }

 .clearfix
 {
display: block;
 }

 /* Panel Tab/button */
.tab
{
background: url(../images/tab_b.png) repeat-x 0 0;
height: 42px;
position: relative;
top: 0;
z-index: 999;
}

.tab ul.login
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    height: 42px;
    width: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 0;
    right: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

    .tab ul.login li.left
    {
        background: url(../images/tab_l.png) no-repeat left 0;
        height: 42px;
        width: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

    .tab ul.login li.right
    {
        background: url(../images/tab_r.png) no-repeat left 0;
        height: 42px;
        width: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

    .tab ul.login li
    {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0 6px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 42px;
        background: url(../images/tab_m.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    }

        .tab ul.login li a
        {
            color: #15ADFF;
        }

            .tab ul.login li a:hover
            {
                color: white;
            }

.tab .sep
{
    color: #414141;
}

.tab a.open, .tab a.close
{
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
}

.tab a.open
{
    background: url(../images/bt_open.png) no-repeat left 0;
}

.tab a.close
{
    background: url(../images/bt_close.png) no-repeat left 0;
}

.tab a:hover.open
{
    background: url(../images/bt_open.png) no-repeat left -19px;
}

.tab a:hover.close
{
    background: url(../images/bt_close.png) no-repeat left -19px;
}

/* sliding panel */
#toppanel
{
position: absolute; /*Panel will overlap  content */
/*position: relative;*/ /*Panel will "push" the content down */
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
 }

 #panel
 {
width: 100%;
height: 270px;
color: #999999;
background: #272727;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 3;
display: none;
 }

#panel h1
{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding: 5px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
}

#panel h2
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 0 5px;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
 }

#panel p
 {
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#panel a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #15ADFF;
 }

    #panel a:hover
    {
        color: white;
     }

#panel a-lost-pwd
 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#panel .content
 {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.85em;
 }

    #panel .content .left
    {
         width: 280px;
        float: left;
        padding: 0 15px;
        border-left: 1px solid #333;
    }

    #panel .content .right
     {
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
    }

    #panel .content form
     {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    #panel .content label
     {
        float: left;
        padding-top: 8px;
        clear: both;
        width: 280px;
        display: block;
    }

     #panel .content input.field
    {
        border: 1px #1A1A1A solid;
        background: #414141;
        margin-right: 5px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        width: 200px;
        color: white;
        height: 16px;
    }

    #panel .content input:focus.field
    {
        background: #545454;
    }

    /* BUTTONS */
    /* Login and Register buttons */
    #panel .content input.bt_login, #panel .content input.bt_register
{
display: block;
float: left;
clear: left;
height: 34px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0px 0 10px;
vertical-align: super;
line-height: 54px;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
font-variant: small-caps;
text-transform: capitalize;
color: #000000;
} 

    #panel .content input.bt_login
    {
        width: 74px;
        background: transparent url(../images/bt_login.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    }

    #panel .content input.bt_register
    {
        width: 94px;
        color: white;
        background: transparent url(../images/bt_register.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    }

#panel .lost-pwd
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    padding: 15px 5px 0;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: any chance you create a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: Change the `line-height`.

Comment: @Franscisco Changing the margin moves the button and text but not the text within the button.

Comment: @Leon never used jsfiddle - I will have a look at it now.

Answer (score 2):

Change `line-height: normal;` to `line-height: 34px;`. If you make the `line-height` the same as the `height` the text will center vertically.

**Edit**

You can also change the `padding` of the button to adjust the text. Although not the prefered method IMO, it will still work.

Comment: @DaveGordon Seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/qv89j/ Is there any other CSS being applied to the button?

Comment: Ok, so based on your CSS, it appears that your buttons are using images as their background, correct? The HTML you provided doesn't match up with the image you posted though so it's difficult to test. At this point, I think you'd be best off creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and trying your best to recreate your issue in there. Once you've been able to replicate your issue in a fiddle, then we can get a clearer picture of what is causing the problem exactly. Like I said, adjusting the `line-height` should work, so my guess is that there is a problem with the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

What I ended up doing was removing the form and changing this

```
<input class="field" type="text" name="signup" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
```

To an Asp:Button and assigning the css to it's class. like this

```
<asp:Button ID="signup" runat="server" class="button"/>
```

Which did the trick.